# Does libjit dynamically translate a piece of code to something executable?

Tags: c

Is GNU libjit meant to translate a piece of code into something executable (say, machine code for x86) at run time?  I don't see how the examples from the [libjit tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/doc/libjit_3.html) actually shows this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What part of the process in particular are you expecting to be shown?

Comment: Wonder if it's possible to create software that receives a piece of code and dynamically generate code and execute it.  It's easy if it's in scripting language ("eval" type of call will do), but the code base is C.  By the way, this software will only receive code from reliable source.

Comment: You should define what exactly "a piece of code" means to you.

Comment: I had thought a piece of code could be C code snippet, but as @duskwuff pointed out, it's a different subject that's not covered by libjit.

Answer (score 1):

Not as a single step. It's probably more appropriate to say that libjit can generate executable code in memory, *if given* a low-level description of what that code should do. That's what the calls to functions like `jit_insn_add()` in the tutorial are all about; libjit converts a sequence of *notional instructions* (e.g, "add register 1 to register 2", "perform the next block of instructions if register 3 is zero") fed to it into a sequence of bytes in memory which can be run by your CPU to perform those operations.

If you want to convert a *textual representation of some code* (e.g, the string `a = b + c;`) to executable code of some variety, that's an entirely different and unrelated task. A full explanation of everything involved is beyond the scope of an answer on this site, but a general study of formal compiler implementation would be my recommended starting point. (Ignore for a moment that you intend to execute this code at runtime, rather than compiling it to an executable; this has surprisingly little bearing on the techniques used.) An excellent textbook on the subject is "[Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)", aka. the "Dragon Book".

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff for the answer.  Sounds like one should be able to write a libjit based program to accept "assembly" like instructions in run time (say, from network socket) and generate the machine code and execute it, is that right?   The tutorial doesn't show how it is possible.